# Why wouldn't you make a nested class static?

Tags: java, nested-class

If I have class with a nested class, why wouldn't you want it to be static? Is there even a way for two instances of the same class to have different nested classes?

For example:

```
class MyClass {  
    public static class myInnerClass {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> why wouldn't you want it to be static

Because I want it to access instance data of a parent object.

> Is there even a way for two instances of the same class to have different nested classes?

What do you mean by `have`? Declared? A class has only one declaration where you list all nested classes. So, in this case the answer is no.

Comment: I didn't know about non-static inner classes having access to the parenting class's fields, that explains my queries. By "have" I meant two different declarations. Thank you. :)

Comment: It's worth noting that if you don't *need* it to be `static`, it shouldn't be. Using non-`static` inner classes can lead to memory leaks because of that implicit reference to the instance of the outer class. If you don't need that reference, don't make it non-`static`.

Answer (score 3):

Take for example a `Comparator` or `Runnable` (multi-threading) implementations. This is a classic example when you need an extra class that has access to the current instance's fields and methods but is of no use outside of that class. However, static classes could be useful outside the enclosing type, too.

```
public class EnclosingType
{

    private static final class StaticRunnableImplementation implements Runnable
    {
        private final EnclosingType instance;

        public StaticRunnableImplementation(EnclosingType instance)
        {
            this.instance = instance;
        }

        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            instance.getSomething();
            //getSomething() leads to compile error
        }
    }

    public class NonStaticRunnableImplementation implements Runnable
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            doStuff();
        }

    }

    public int getSomething()
    {
        return 42;
    } 

    public synchronized void doStuff()
    {
        ;
    }

    public void doSomething()
    {
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new StaticRunnableImplementation(this));
        Thread t2 = new Thread(new NonStaticRunnableImplementation());

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }
}
```

The access to the non-static methods and fields of current instance of the enclosing type, wouldn't be possible if the nested classes would be declared static.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if I understand your question correctly, but the difference between a static inner class to a non-static is that the second needs a reference from the parent class to be created.

It's preferable to create static class, because of "hidden ciclic references" that can be created. For example, it's normal in GUI developing you do something like

```
public class View {
    private Table table;        
    ...
    private void addListeners() {
        this.table.addListener(new TableSelectionListener());
    }

    privte class TableSelectionListener implements Table.SelectionListener {
        @Overrides
        public void selected(SelectionEvent evt) { /* do stuff.*/ }
    }
}
```

Lots of programmers don't realize, but you now have a circular reference between `View` and `Table`, because `SelectionListener`, being non static, saves a reference to its parent. So

> View -> Table -> TableSelectionListener --> View

If you declare `TableSelectionListener` `static` it will only need the "namespace" from view to be created, but besides that, it will not save a reference to any `View` unless you save it on a field. But then, you will return to the first problem :P

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Circular references are not a problem for the JVM, they do not prevent garbage collection by themselves. Once no external reference exists to any objects of that particular graph, it will be eligible for GC.

Comment: Well, that made me do some research. JVM is really powerfull. Anyway, I would even then emphatize the use of static nested inner class :P

Answer (score 0):

A [non-static nested class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html) is associated and has access to the members of an enclosing class instance:

> Non-static nested classes (inner classes) have access to other members of the enclosing class, even if they are declared private.

Answer (score 0):

If you implement a `Listener` of some kind, for example, you usually want to call a method on the outer class when you receive the event. In that case, an inner class is simpler than a nested class with an explicit reference to the outer class instance.

That's often used in GUI components. For example (using an API which doesn't actually exist):

```
public class CircleView extends View {
     private final Circle circle = new Circle();
     private final Button button = new Button();

     public CircleView() {
         circle.setColor(Color.RED);
         button.addClickListener(new MyClickListener());
     }

     private toggleColor() {
         circle.setColor(circle.getColor() == Color.RED ? Color.BLUE : Color.RED);
     }

     private class MyClickListener implements ClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick() {
             // Only possible because of the implicit reference:
             toggleColor();
         }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A non-static nested class allows the following in an *implicit/magical* way:

```
class MyClass {  
    public static class MyInnerClass {
        final MyClass myClass_this;
        public MyInnerClass(MyClass parent) {
            // Nested class instance has/keeps access to "parent" object.
            // In a nested non-static class the "parent" is -guaranteed- to be
            // non-null as the nested class can only be created with
            // an instance of the containing class.
            myClass_this = parent;
        }
        public Foo bar() {
            // Use myClass_this
            // Would be available as MyClass.this or implicit resolution in a
            // a nested non-static class.
        }
    }
}
```

The rules for scope access are also a bit different but the above should show when it might be useful/desirable. In both cases there is only one *type* for the inner class (`MyClass$MyInnerClass`), although there can be many instances.

Wether or not this is a "good" thing to have such non-static nested type behavior is debatable, but it *is* provided in Java.

However, **one case where this "non-static" behavior is extremely useful in Java is with anonymous classes (e.g. event handlers or callbacks) which behave as non-static nested classes;** while a "different" construct the same mechanism allows accessing methods defined in the enclosing type. Moving the anonymous classes to non-static nested classes can thus merely be viewed as an extension of this common idiom that also allows exposing the nominative type.

(C# has no notion of a "non-static" nested class, but it is easy to emulate it as per above - although I would argue it's usually better to pass a more-refined interface. In addition, other constructs such as closures minimize the need/use even more.)